# Spring boot Http Security config unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In My Spring boot application, I have a security config class for which I am trying to write a unit test for. This is my first time doing it so I need some assistance.  Here is the code below. Please some help would be much appreciated. Thank you

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private String id;
private String pwd;
private String role;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    //This allows to view h2 console during development
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
            withUser(id).
            password(pwd).
            roles(role);
}}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I am trying to unit test this class but not sure how to go about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend writing a unit test for the configuration class itself. Generally, an integration test that proves the functionality of your app, say using [Mock MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html), works best.

I realize this isn't what you asked; however, if you take a look at the spring security repo, you'll see that this is precisely how they do it, too. i.e., to test their configurers, [they use integration tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/config/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers).